# WPF - button with text and image

Tags: wpf, button

Cant make button in WPF app with image and text on it. My code is like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WindowR.One"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WindowR"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="One" Height="300" Width="300">

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="Click Here" />
            <Image Source="D:\Skola\4. semester\TP\GIT folder\Visualko\Core\WindowR\Pictures\0.png" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

But the text isnt above image..tried lots of tutorials from here..but none of them work properly

Comment: `StackPanel` arranges TextBlock next to Image. Try to use `Grid`

Comment: @RadoInko set `Orientation` to vertical

Comment: Do i miss something? Image and Text are still next to each other and not one over another

Comment: The code as now presented should work. Does the visual designer show the correct layout?

Comment: The code you have now differs from what you had in the first version of this post. Looks like  you have copied code from a now-deleted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StackPanel` arranges TextBlock next to Image. Try to use `Grid`

```
<Button Width="120" Height="50" >
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="D:\Skola\4. semester\TP\GIT folder\Visualko\Core\WindowR\Pictures\0.png" />
        <TextBlock Text="Click Here" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

Comment: Not true. The code as now presented should work. If you try it the image is displayed below the text.

Comment: @ChrisF, maybe. we need feedback from OP. in my understanding the requirement is to have "text above image in a button".

Comment: Which should "just work" with a stack panel, even one inside a button with a specified height and width. I'm suspicious that the question changed after I posted my (now deleted) answer.

Comment: @ChrisF, StackPanel arranges elements differently: they are side by side. The question was changed because OP tried our suggestions

Comment: Yes i edited my question. Sorry for that. But this works good. Code in my answer dont work. It was still next to each other. Thank you..People here in SO are rly fast and willing.