# adding a image to button programmatically with text content

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to add a image to a button programmatically using the code below

When I try and do it with just var image the image loads in the button just fine. However if I try and add a string before the image I get the string value and then I get "myStringSystem.Windows.Controls.Image" which is displayed inside the button content

Is it possible to get the image and string inside the content property?

I have looked at this post [WPF - button with text and image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37102779/wpf-button-with-text-and-image)

and I am attempting to do this in code behind and not in XAML

````
 foreach (var wpt in waypointFPL)
            {

                System.Windows.Controls.Button newBtn = new Button();
                newBtn.Background =  System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
                newBtn.Foreground =  System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Cyan;
                newBtn.BorderBrush = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
                newBtn.Height = 75;
                newBtn.Width = 440;
                newBtn.FontSize = 30;


                var image =  new System.Windows.Controls.Image
                {
                    
                    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\ProgramData\InkSadge\Images\AP.png")),
                    Width = 63,
                    Height = 63,
                    
                };

                newBtn.Content = wpt+ image;
                

                FlightPlanStackPanel.Children.Add(newBtn);

            } ```
````

Comment: You can't simply combine strings and UI elements by using the `+` operator. The Button's Content should be a Panel that has an Image and a TextBlock as child elements.

Comment: Instead of a hardcoded path, better use `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), @"InkSadge\Images\AP.png");`